# how to pass variables into jquery.getScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been looking at the jquery website but I don't think I'm quite understanding this as I'm not seeing any console.logs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=[1,2,3];
    var b='foo';
    var c={'bar':'baz'};

    $.getScript('script.js',function(a,b,c){
        console.log('how can i see a='+a+', b='+b+' and c='+c+' inside here?');
        });
    });
```

Comment: this works here: http://jsfiddle.net/rYQkx/ without redifining variable as local

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script [is executed in the global context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), so simply don't pass arguments (they're shadowing those defined by the script)  :

```
$.getScript('script.js',function(){
    // use a, b and c here
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: nope I can't log anything that way ether. I do this console.log(a); and I see nothing.

Comment: @BenMuircroft because i guess your variables are not globals. See when variables are on same scope: http://jsfiddle.net/5FCej/

Comment: @BenMuircroft Then just don't declare them as arguments to the callback (i.e. change `function(a,b,c)` to `function()`).